# How to resolve 'readLines' error in Android Studios

Tags: java, android

I'm currently building an app with Java on Android Studios but I ran into a problem.

```
items = new ArrayList<>(FileUtils.readLines(getDataFile(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

I get an error from this line saying 'cannot resolve method readLines'

My dependencies in my build.gradle are as followed

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6' //First tried this one
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2' //Then tried this one
}
```

The bottom two lines are what I tried to use to solve the issue but I still get the error.

I also have `import android.os.FileUtils;` in my java class but still nothing. Please help!

Comment: This method does not exist - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUtils

Comment: Im watching someone use it right now though on a tutorial that was posted in 2019?

Comment: Double check his imports he is probably using Commons-IO.

Comment: He is, but what does that mean? Is it outdated and not used anymore?

Comment: Commons IO is a library provided by the Apache group that compiles a bunch of great functions and utilities. It is a great library I highly recommend it for non Android Java projects. The Issue with Android projects is some devices (Huawei) bundle Commons IO so you are stuck with an older version of the library that you cannot update. There are some great articles online search "Java Read File Line by Line" to find some good tutorials on how to do it manually if you don't want to use Commons IO

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, please, explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'` from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/dependency-info.html. Then import it in your project like this `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`. Make sure you're not importing **android.os.FileUtils** already.